# Post Format problem

Tags: posts, loop, post-formats

I'v tried really a lot of solutions, and the one that works, it works half a way.

Inside single.php I'v added

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php if( has_post_format('video')) {

get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'video'); } ?>
```

Then i created content-video.php. Now the thing is it appears as it should but since it's called inside single.php for some reason the function doesnt stop, like, if it has format video show the post trough content-video.php only, if the post it's not video post format run a normal post (single.php).

A reason why i want to do this, is that i want to style differently video post formats.
So what do I currently have? I have the one i want (video post format) but below it's again the whole single.php stuff. So again the post, the image, the title, the sidebar.

I guess i only need to stop the loop in single if it has post format video, but cant figure/see a way.

My single.php it's here http://pastebin.com/XwqiZrEd

So what I'm missing, because in 4am i am missing something for sure :D ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about add `else {` after `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'video'); }`?

EDIT (1) :

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying single posts.
*
* @package SN
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if( has_post_format('video')) {
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'video'); }else{ ?>        
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php if( 'scoreboard' == get_post_type() ) {  ?>
  <?php } else { ?>
         <?php
    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'sport-news' ),
        'after'  => '</div>',
                     ) );?>
       </div><!-- .entry-content -->
       </header> 
       <?php } 
          }?>
     <footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php sport_news_entry_footer(); ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

Comment: Hey Kika, well that's the first thing i have tried, but getting an error. I understand that i need to add else and close it, but cant find a right way, where/how to add it inside single. That's what you get when you work so late. So inside else i would have to add basically a whole single.php?

Comment: I edited my post with full your code after editing.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was doing that, but i guess on the wrong way. This was the issue, at the bottom <?php } }?> and i was trying to add it twice. Thanks so much, kind regards.

Comment: Could i bother you for one more thing. Already tried to move the closing part everywhere but currently it shows sidebar from single.php and i dont want sidebar there. Where to add it so the sidebar doesnt get called inside video format - post. There is an endwhile and if add it below it, an error, if i add it above, still sidebar gets called. Any idea? Sorry for bothering you, i just recently started to learn php :D

Comment: Would this be a right way to do it. It works, but not sure is this the way to do it. I moved the endwhile below sidebar call <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- #content-wrapper -->
<?php }  }?>
<?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

Comment: if you need to remove sidebar in video format but keep it in other formats you should do one of this : **1** : move <?php endwhile; after get_sidebar and add if condition like above one. or **2** :   Edit content-video.php and add at end of file the footer part and move end of else at end of single.php

Comment: Yea i moved <?php endwhile; after get_sidebar. You r awesome! Have a nice day! Thanks